# What is the class group of the complement of three lines in the projective plane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a straightforward question :

> Let $ Y$ be the union of the three lines $ L_1:x=0 , L_2 :y=0$ and $L_3:z=0$ in the Projective plane $\mathbb{P }^2$. What is the Class group of the Complement $U:=\mathbb{P}^2\setminus Y$ ?

Now all the main conditions required to define the class group are satisfied: Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a noetherian integral scheme which is regular in  codimension one i.e. all local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ have dimension one and are regular. 
The Class group $Cl(X)$ is defined as

$$ Div(X)/\sim  $$
with 
$$ D\sim D' \iff D-D' \text{ is a principal divisor }$$

I tried to use the theorem that for any hyperplane $H:x_i=0$, if $D$ is a divisor of degree $d$ then $D\sim dH$.

I also know that if  $W$ is a closed irreducible subset of $X$ codimension $1$, and $V=X\setminus W$, then there is a exact sequence:

$$\mathbb{Z} \to CL(X)\to CL(V)\to 0$$

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here $Y$ is not irreducible and your exact sequence does not apply ( irreducibility of $U$ is irrelevant) .

Answer (score 1):

The class group of $U$ is zero, dear Fellow Mathematician.

Indeed if you remove the line $z=0$ from $\mathbb P^2$, you are left with $\mathbb A^2$.
And if you then remove the points where $x=0$ or $y=0$ you are left with the product $U=(\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\})\times (A^1\setminus\{0\})$.
This is an affine variety with coordinate ring
$$A=\mathcal O(Y)=k[T,T^{-1},U,U^{-1}]$$ 
Since that ring is factorial the corresponding affine  variety $Y$ has zero class group:  Hartshorne, Chapter II, Proposition  6.2 .

Comment: Thank you, George. I guess I it is all in basics. The two points that you make are great. I will think about them

Comment: Not so basic: there is a big temptation to claim that  the answer is $\mathbb Z/3$ due to the exact sequence you display, forgetting the irreducibility condition on the closed subvariety.

Comment: So far I understand the removal of one point giving me the  affine plane then if remove the two other points then I get the product of the the two affine lines withoit the zero. Now If I have  prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$  that defines my closed set $Y$ - I assume it is the zero ideal - I know that $k[x,y]/\mathfrak{p} $ must be the respected ring that I want to take the spectrum of. Looking at the contruction of this ring $k[x,y]/\mathfrak{p} $  I can also write it as $k[t,t^-1,s,s^-1 ] $  now this is ring is UFD and so with hartshorne II.6.2 the class group must have been zero.

Comment: No, no: you have to remove the  projective  **line**  $z=0$ first and then, in the resulting affine plane, remove the union $xy=0$ of the two affine intersecting **lines** $x=0$ and $y=0$ .

Comment: Ok I meant af course line not point. Meaning $\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus \{ z=0\} $ is $\mathbb{A}^2$. if I take out the other lines I get $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus \{y=0,\ x=0 \}$ then I should get yours $\mathbb{A}\setminus 0 \times \mathbb{A}\setminus 0 $. now finally if this union $\{y=0,\ x=0 \}$ is represented by some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ then It should be argument that I used from above for   $k[x,y]_{\mathfrak{p}} $